# Conditionally select data from column decision

Tags: sql, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am trying to select PatientID, FirstName, LastName, and TreatmentCode from the Patient table IF the TreatmentCode is not NULL. I keep getting this message:

Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'TreatmentCode'.

Here's my current query:

```
IF (TreatmentCode != NULL)
    BEGIN
       SELECT PatientID,
              FirstName,
              LastName,
              TreatmentCode
       FROM sqldb.dbo.Patient
    END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `WHERE`:

```
SELECT PatientID,
       FirstName,
       LastName,
       TreatmentCode
FROM sqldb.dbo.Patient
WHERE TreatmentCode IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: That works! Why is my column name invalid in my first example?

Comment: @SavageCoder There are 2 errors: 1) You cannot refer to column without `FROM` clause 2) col != NULL always yields UNKNOWN(it could never be true)